# PHP global scope and Amp async parallel execution

Tags: php, multithreading, parallel-processing, global, amphp

I'm using [AMP ParallelFunctions](https://amphp.org/parallel-functions/) and [AMP Promise wait](https://amphp.org/amp/promises/) to create an async execution in PHP. The idea is to call multiple HTTP endpoints simultaneously and wait until all of them are resolved.

The code looks something like this:

```
$result = wait( parallelMap( $myArray, function($item) use ($api) {
   return $api->call_api( $item );
} ) );
```

The function `$api->call_api` lives on a different file and uses a Bearer token from a global constant, it throws the error `PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant API_TOKEN` every time it's invoked by the async process (it runs ok as a synchronous process)

I suspect this happens because `parallelMap` is a PHP worker that doesn't have access to the same scope where `API_TOKEN` was defined.

Any ideas how to make wait and parallelMap to recognize a variable defined by `define('API_TOKEN', 'my-value')`?

Comment: `use ($api, $token)`

Comment: Thanks, Sammitch. I'd like to avoid the implementation of `call_api`, I'd prefer to just use it as is, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happens because PHP Thread Workers don't have access to the global scope where constants were defined.

I ended up passing creating a local variable, assigning the global variable to it, and then pass it to the anonymous function, as Sammitch suggested.

Something like this:

```
$my_global = GLOBAL_CONSTANT;
$result = wait( parallelMap( $myArray, function($item) use ($api, $my_global) {
   return $api->call_api( $item, $my_global );
} ) );
```

This approach as also suggested by people that give maintenance to this package:

https://github.com/amphp/amp/issues/361